# Why does my IndexedDB save function not work?

Tags: microsoft-edge, web-extension, webextension-storage

I am making an edge web extension game, I've got the game done, so now i have to do storage.
I will use IndexedDB because webSQL will no longer be available soon.
I made a save function, but i got an error.

This is the function that calls the save function every 2 seconds:

```
function init() {
  const data = { 
  money: money, 
  monkey: monkey 
  };
  setInterval(function() {
  saveGameData("myDatabase", "store", data); }, 2000);
}
```

And this is the save function:

```
function saveGameData(databaseName, storeName, data) {
  // Open the database
  const request = indexedDB.open(databaseName, 1);
  
  request.onerror = function() {
    console.error("Database error:", request.error);
  };
  
  request.onsuccess = function() {
    const db = request.result;
    
    // Start a transaction and get the object store
    const transaction = db.transaction(storeName, "readwrite");
    const objectStore = transaction.objectStore(storeName);
    
    // Save the data to the object store
    const saveRequest = objectStore.put(data);
    
    saveRequest.onerror = function() {
      console.error("Error saving data:", saveRequest.error);
    };
    
    saveRequest.onsuccess = function() {
      console.log("Data saved successfully");
    };
  };
}
```

And this is the error i get:

> Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found.

The error is from this line:
`const transaction = db.transaction(storeName, "readwrite");`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have missed the `onupgradeneeded` event. For more information, you can refer to [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB#creating_or_updating_the_version_of_the_database).

If you have already called `onupgradeneeded` event, try changing the version number.